# Mysql root user can't create table or other super user tasks

Tags: mysql

**Server version: 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)**

I'm having some weird issues on my `root` user on MySQL. Read a bunch of posts now but not finding a solution.

When I try to create a database:

```
mysql> create database test;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'test'
```

So the root user isn't able to create a database. Also not able to select e.g. `mysql.user` table or:

```
mysql> flush privileges;
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the RELOAD privilege(s) for this operation
```

Permissions however seem right:

```
mysql> select user();
+------------------------------------+
| user()                             |
+------------------------------------+
| root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal |
+------------------------------------+

mysql> select current_user();
+----------------+
| current_user() |
+----------------+
| root@%         |
+----------------+


mysql> show grants;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@%                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION                |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `ditto`.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have super user access on the database it seems to me.

As it is a live production server, I can't close the server and restart with `--skip-grant-tables`. Why could this be and how could I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by running MySQL with `skip-grant-tables` to get full access and then fixing the `mysql.user` table. There were 3 root user entries for different environments and they didn't have the right permissions.